# Update specific field in mongoDB in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, I'm using it with c# with the latest driver.... just want to update a specific field like name? How can I do this (console based app)? I've tried so many times but fails, there are update methods but can't figure out how to use them... can anybody help me ???

This is my Code:

```
 class Student
    {
        public int age { get;  set; }
        public string name { get;  set; }
        public ObjectId id { get;  set; }
        public string fname { get;  set; }

        public Student() { }

        public Student(string name, string fname, int age)
        {

            this.name = name;
            this.fname = fname;
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            var db = client.GetDatabase("StudentDB");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("Student");

            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for Insert \nPress 2 for Search \nPress 3 for Update \nPress 4 for Delete ");

            int _case = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (_case)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Father Name");
                    string father_name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Age");
                    int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Student s = new Student(name, father_name, age);
                    collection.InsertOne(s);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //Search by Age
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Age");
                    int _age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    var query = from person in collection.AsQueryable<Student>()
                                where person.age > _age
                                select person;
                    foreach (Student q in query)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(q.name + " " + q.fname + " " + q.age);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:





                case 4:
                    //Delete
                    int in_age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    collection.DeleteOne(z => z.age == in_age);
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleted");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected wrong option");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to simplify it to just the update case you need help with and then show what you're trying with that case that's not working?

Comment: Ask user to input name or id and load object with it into Student instance. Then change student instance name attribute to new one (which is asked from user) and store changed student back to database with update.